# When not to use two way SSL certification validation

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a Java based backend application that only performs read operations. The way the backend works is that the user places a customer unique identifier and from that i.d. it returns back the customer's information. This backend application only gets called by internal teams within the company. This led me to ask when not to use SSL certification verification? Is two way SSL certification necessary for this application which only gets called by teams internal to the company?

Comment: Are you asking about server or client certificates? If server only, is the API open for anyone to call, or do you validate client, e.g. with user/password? If yes, then you need SSL to provide the encryption to protect the user/password from snooping, and yes, even on the internal network.

Comment: @Andreas It is server. I do have java back end code that validates the JSON request that the request that is coming in is part of the allowed clients. And nope, nothing with username/password.

Comment: So how do you validate "allowed clients", if a client doesn't identify itself? And if a client does identify itself somehow, can someone snooping on the communication spoof that and pretend to be an allowed client? If yes, then you need to secure the identifying piece of information, so snoopers cannot see it.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, if someone is snooping around and they know the allowed client ids they can spoof it.

Comment: So there is your answer. You need SSL.

Comment: Why should one not want to enforce SSL/TLS in 2018? Always a good decision. What is your definition of "two way", client certificates? Encryption and authentication are different things...

Comment: @home By authentication we already have that by that  I mean , "External Clients can be used wiht https ://<url>". By two way SSL i mean both clients will have strict two way SSL certification validation.

Comment: @home There are definitely applications that doesn't need SSL. Not every application needs it

Comment: First stop saying SSL, TLS was invented **20** years ago to replace it. Then you seem to mix 2 (of the 3) properties that a protocol like TLS offers you: you have confidentiality (encryption), and authentication (with X.509 certificates typically), the third one being integrity. For confidentiality, you need TLS. Then the question is on authentication. Contrary to popular belief this is more important than confidentiality. At the minimum the clients MUST check the chain of trust regarding server certificate. As for client certificats, it depends how you want to authenticate your clients.

Comment: And you can do TLS without using certificates, like with a shared key/password. While rare, it exists in the protocol as it has some use cases.

Comment: You are asking questions which only you can answer. And stackoverflow, as a question-and-answer site, is not well suited to discussions which are basically conversations.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that is not true. I asked a very general question. When not to use certificates. how more general can that get

Comment: General == bad fit for stackoverflow. From the help pages: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @JamesKPolk Blah! There is absolutely nothing wrong with this question. I aksed when not to use SSL certificate which is practical, answerable and based off actual problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Java. And highly depends on your company’s security policy.

If customer information is public within company, you don’t need authentication at all. If it is not public, you need authentication. (So your Backend can check whether the user is authorized to see that info or not)

Usually, your company will prescribe the grade of security required to access information depending on its confidentiality classification.

**UPDATE** few reasons that come to mind (for using or not using SSL)

the only reason NOT to use SSL (like "to strongly try to avoid it") is

- if you have a highly speed-dependend (real time) communication and want to avoid that overhead at all costs

reasons to use it (nowadays you should ALWAYS use at least HTTPS)

- this way, the browser knows who it is talking to (avoiding man-in-the-middle)
- this way the transport is encrypted (someone may have installed listeners on the line)

reasons to use authentication and cheching whether the user is authorized:

- in future, there may be a change in the data classification (e.g. not all employees will be allowed to see that data) => instead of changing the application then, only assignment of permissions will need to be changed.

PS: adding one more thing:

- authentication methods (basic vs. client side certificate vs. other methods) will still depend on the use case and confidentiality classification

Comment: Yes, customer info is public within the company. And IT for a specific team has mandated to use SSL even though the info that is being retrieved back doesn't really have private info so I am not sure they know the reasons behind using SSL. The info that gets retrieved back in this application is only emails and sms that were sent from the company to the customer. But within that email and sms doesn't contain private info. If it does contain private info we already have logic that will encrypt it.

Comment: Well. That’s nothing, stackoverflow can help you with. It’s a discussion with your security department. BTW, is there a reason, why you want to avoid ssl?

Comment: It was more of a general question which is why I posted on here. I wanted to know when not to use it. Just wanted to give a background of why I asked the question. No reason to avoid it, just want to follow best practices and understand the reasons behind it. But from my discussion with you and Andreas it does seem like I need it. Do you mind adding more points to your answer like when to use it and when NOT to use it?